# How can I create a web service in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a simple web service in rails 3, but when I use `rails g web_services remote` it doesn't work, the error is: `Could not find generator web_service.`

I tried to install actionwebservice gem, but the problem continues...

What should I do here?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actionwebservice is a very, very, very old gem. If you're looking to create an API then I would take a look at [Grape](http://github.com/intridea/grape) and see if that fits your need.

Answer (score 0):

If you would create a rest api  " [without any gem](https://labs.kollegorna.se/blog/2015/04/build-an-api-now/)  " . if you want using gem use " either [Grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape) " or " [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) " as per your requirements.